# Why does the console REPL parse input differently from ToExpression?

Tags: string-manipulation, kernel, input, parsing

In the console REPL, we can see that input is parsed in a certain way, that is not equivalent to simply calling ToExpression on the input string. From math.exe using Mathematica 13.1:

```
In[1]:= Print@"foo"\[NewLine]Print@"bar"
foo

In[2]:= DownValues[In][[1]]

Out[2]= HoldPattern[In[1]] :> Print["foo"]

In[3]:= ToExpression[InString[1]]
foo
bar
```

As we can see, the Print["bar"] is discarded when assigning In[1], but not when assigning InString[1], and calling ToExpression on InString[1] evaluates both print statements. What is the meaning of this, and is there a function analogous to ToExpression which reproduces the former behavior?

Comment: Use `Print@"foo"; Print@"bar"` instead.

Comment: I understand perfectly well that using CompoundExpression is correct. However, my specific question is, why does the console REPL parse my particular example input string differently from calling ToExpression on InputString?

Comment: Because the input you type is not a string, but output of `InString[1]` is a string.

Comment: I supposed I do not understand in precise enough detail how the main loop works. I was under the impression, based on the documentation of $PreRead, that input is given into the main loop as a string, the value of PreRead applied, and only then parsed into an expression for evaluation.

Comment: I do not get the same results as you.  When I open the kernel from the command line I get [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/BSnFai6j), where you see that `ToExpression[InString[1]]` only prints "foo" and not "bar", which makes sense - I've tried on Windows, Linux, and Mac and cannot reproduce

Answer (score 1):

Input that is typed is not a string but output of `InString[1]` is a string.

So if you use `FullForm`:

```
In[28]:= FullForm[InString[1]]

Out[28]//FullForm= "Print@\"foo\"\\[NewLine]Print@\"bar\""
```

you see that the string generated by `InString` is a bit different than what you typed. Or more precisely it is the same but it is enclosed inside `""` which original input is not.

Comment: I find this confusing, because if you define a value such as $PreRead = (Print[FullForm[#]]; #) &; , then you will see that it prints the value of input string, but only then evaluates the input, but it /only evaluates the first Print statement/, indicating that it is doing something to the value of InputString other than simply calling ToExpression, as it does to code passed on the -run switch from the command line. This seems surprising to me, but perhaps I'm naive.

Comment: Based on some experimentation, it seems the main loop may be doing something like this: InString[1]//(Function[x,SetDelayed[In[1],x],HoldAllComplete]@@Take[ToExpression[#,InputForm,HoldComplete],1];Out[1]=In[1])&

Comment: Your code with `$PreRead` works as expected, what is wrong with it? It prints the full-form of the input as a string and then evaluates the original input same way as it would do without  `$PreRead`.